# Measure the time it takes to store data in the blockchain using Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, execution-time, performance-measuring

I used **Hyperledger Fabric** to build an application. For, chaincode and api I used **JavaScript**.

Now, I want to find out how much time it takes to store the data in the ledger. How can I do this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For simple metrics, you may use some [builtin JS functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) to calculate the time for contract.submitTransaction() function. For in depth tracing there are tools like Jaeger.